# List with n elements where n is a variable

Tags: list-manipulation

I defined a function with `n` terms where `n` is a variable:

```
LogLH[μ_, σ_] = n Log[a[σ]] - Sum[Log[y[[i]]] +  
(Log[y[[i]]] - μ)^2 / (2 σ^2), {i, 1, n}]
```

In this function, the `y[[i]]` are (assumed to represent) observations of a quantity - picked from a list of `n` elements.

This statement multiply produces the error "The expression i cannot be used as a part specification". It seems however, that M. correctly evaluates the function. M. also computes the partial derivatives for μ and σ. But the above errors repeat and lateron, I can not apply the Solve command to the resulting system of equations. Hence my question: How can I define an open ended list of n elements in M.?

Comment: Use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) instead of `Set` (`=`). Afterwards, once you provide a proper list `y` and a value for `n`, the sum will evaluate. E.g., `n = 10;
y = Range@10;
LogLH[m, s]`. The rest of your question is uncear: what is "M."? What inequalities? What system of equations? What about the derivatives of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) in your function definition. Next, if you use a list in the step definition then the Sum will step through its elements (rather than going over an integer range).

```
LogLH[μ_, σ_] := n Log[a[σ]] - Sum[
    Log[y] +  (Log[y] - μ)^2 / (2 σ^2), 
    {i, y}
 ]
```

So now when you use LogLH the *y* will stay as a symbol like this:

```
LogLH[1, 2]
(* -y (1/8 (-1 + Log[y])^2 + Log[y]) + n Log[a[2]] *)
```

until you set *y* to a list, then *i* will step through the values of *y*:

```
y = {1, 2, 3};
LogLH[1, 2]
(* {-(3/8) + n Log[a[2]], -(3/8) (-1 + Log[2])^2 - 3 Log[2] + 
      n Log[a[2]], -(3/8) (-1 + Log[3])^2 - 3 Log[3] + n Log[a[2]]} *)
```

If Solve does not work for your system of equations, you could also try [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) or [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

Comment: Your approach eliminates the sum - which is however essential for later analytical treadment of the problem. Think e. g. of the basic problem of calculating a mean. You have n observations with values y[[i]], but for the formula you do not have these y[[i]] nor the n.

Comment: Now consider s2 to be a function of yq and you want to find the derivative of it.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) instead of `Set` (`=`). Next, I'd propose to incorporate the list `y` as an argument of the function, as "`y[[i]]` are (...) observations of a quantity - picked from a list of `n` elements", hence `n = Length[y]`:

```
LogLH[μ_, σ_, y_List] := 
 Length[y] Log[a[σ]] - Sum[Log[y[[i]]] + (Log[y[[i]]] - μ)^2/(2 σ^2), 
    {i, 1, Length[y]}]
```

E.g.,

```
LogLH[2, 0.5, Range[5]]
```

> -18.8866 + 5 Log[a[0.5]]

The OP didn't specify neither `a[σ]`, nor "the resulting system of equations". About the derivatives:

```
D[LogLH[μ, σ, Range[5]], μ]
```

[image]

```
D[LogLH[μ, σ, Range[5]], σ]
```

[image]

*Mathematica* won't handle a `Sum` with an unspecified `n`.

Comment: You wrote: Mathematica won't handle a Sum with an unspecified n.
Yes, that's exactly what bothers me. Why not? A function which is the sum of n terms can be differenciated - even if one does not know n.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129545/solve-sum-with-indices).